# Duplicate array key when using while in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have this code:

```
$data = array();
$groupedData = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $row["date"]);
    $groupedData[$date->format("Y")][$date->format("m")][$date->format("d")] = $row;
    $data[] = $date;
}
```

What I am trying to do here is to get all dates from my database and sort them by year/month/day

The problem is that for September 2nd, 2018 I have two rows in mysql which will not be added to my arrays because the "day" will be duplicate.

Instead of  this:

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [September] => Array
                (
                    [02] => text 1
                    [02] => text 2
                    [12] => text 3
                    [31] => text 4
                )

        )

)
```

I get this: (of course the second "day 2" gets omitted because of how arrays works.)

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [September] => Array
                (
                    [02] => text 1
                    [12] => text 3
                    [31] => text 4
                )

        )

)
```

How can I fix this and have unique array keys so I can echo both dates of September 2nd?

Comment: as you will find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-array.html) you are returning and associative array but you can also return a numeric array where you will avoid duplicate keys for days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would at another level into the array. In that case all dates contains an array with the multiple values.

**Like this:**

```
$data = array();
$groupedData = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $row["date"]);
    $groupedData[$date->format("Y")][$date->format("m")][$date->format("d")][] = $row;
    $data[] = $date;
}
```

**Array example:**

```
Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [September] => Array
                (
                    [02] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => text 1
                            [1] => text 2
                        )
                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => text 3
                        )
                    [31] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => text 4
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I can't believe I wasted 2 days with this and the solution was a simple "[ ]". Thank you so much (btw I am a beginner)